# PayPal Silent Post for Data Transfer not working

Tags: paypal

Since last Saturday, May 29, 2015, the Silent Post for Data Transfer has not been working for my test and live accounts on paypal.

Has anyone else experienced a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I received a notification from PayPal that depending on the SSL certificates installed on the server that the POST is being sent to, it may fail.

They recommend changing the endpoint for the silent post to be http vs. https.

I hope this helps someone else.